# Implementing tryFindIndex with option types in F#

Tags: f#

I am new to programming in functional languages. I am attempting to implement the F# tryFindIndex function.

```
let rec tryFindIndex func list =
    match list with
    | [] -> None
    | hd::tl -> if func hd then Some(0)
                else (tryFindIndex func tl) + 1
```

The issue is with the last line, since adding 1 causes the return type to be 'int' instead of 'int option'. I need to track the index recursively.

Comment: You can actually look at the F# source code to find how it was implemented for the compiler.  TryFindIndex is here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L370

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the index as an additional parameter.  If you don't do this, then your function also isn't tail recursive.  Also implement your recursion as a separate loop to hide the index parameter.

```
let tryFindIndex func list =
    let rec loop func list index =
        match list with
        | [] -> None
        | hd::tl -> if func hd then Some(index)
                    else loop func tl (index+1)
    loop func list 0
```

As John noted in the comments, the core library implementation of that looks like this:

```
    let tryFindIndex f list = 
        let rec loop n = function[] -> None | h::t -> if f h then Some n else loop (n+1) t
        loop 0 list
```

Comment: @snf Sorry.  I keep editing it before your edits become effective!

Comment: Perfect. I recognized the need for an additional parameter, but did not did not realize that nesting let statements would solve this. Thanks!

Comment: @airietis The nested let allows you to define a function with local scope and then call it within that scope.  Glad to help.  Also fixed your `Some` to have the index in it.

Comment: Thanks again. Also, the loop function needs to be recursive (add 'rec').

Comment: Oops.  Forgot to move that to the inner loop.

Comment: @mydogisbox No problem, I just edited yours because I was writing the same code.